# How to make a draggable and scrollable map with inertia. C#

Tags: dictionary, unity-game-engine, scroll, drag, pan

i am actually trying to follow this tutorial: "How to create a HTML draggable and scrollable map with inertia using Phaser framework" (google it, www. emanueleferonato .com)

Im using Unity but i configured it "pixel perfect" so i can use directly pixels like in AS3 and flashdevelop.

I basically need to make a map for the game where the player can drag in the X axis of the map.

I have no clue of how to do it, also it should have acceleration and deceleration.

Edit:
As i say before, i am using a custom framework that does not allow components, or UI, it works like FlashDevelop and AS3, so imagine the answer is in AS3.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is way too broad for a QA site.

Comment: @JoeBlow as i mentioned below, it's this map: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2016/01/18/how-to-create-a-html-draggable-and-scrollable-map-with-inertia-using-phaser-framework/

And the thing is i am using a custom framework (in unity) that works like AS3, so imagine the answer must be in FlashDevelop and AS3. NOT unity with Unity components.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking up Unity's UI documentation (AND TUTORIALS!) :D They have really good articles, and the forums are a great resource too.

Regarding your specific problem- [Scroll Rect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ScrollRect.html) is what you are looking for. You can implement 2D dragging, along with acceleratoion, deceleration, and other kinds of UI physics (inertia, elasticity, etc.) with it.
Please look for tutorials if you're just beginning to dabble with these. I hope that helps!

Comment: i'm not using component, only sprites, imagine i'm using AS3

Comment: I would recommend NOT using UI scroll Rect, unless of course your map for some reason is UI. There aren't too many tutorials on it and most are in different languages. I would suggest trying to convert one you can find into whatever language you're using.

Comment: hi @necrolords66 you HAVE TO use Unity.UI.  it is extremely simple. there's no other mechanism to do a scroll.

Comment: hi @savlon.  to implemet a scrolling map in UI requires one thing: **you click the checkbox that says 'scrolling'**.  it's completely built-in.  all you do is drop in the image. there is no other way to do it in Unity.

Comment: in any event this question should be deleted, it is far too general for a QA site.

Comment: @JoeBlow , imagine i am using AS3 and FlashDevelop, i can't use component or UI, the map is the same that's here http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2016/01/18/how-to-create-a-html-draggable-and-scrollable-map-with-inertia-using-phaser-framework/

Comment: @necrolords66 If you want to use something you export from AS3 and FlashDevelop in Unity, you will have to look for a plugin that can help use it in Unity (or write one yourself).

Comment: @JoeBlow I assume you're talking about a minimap? I assumed he was talking about an entire map. For example a map like clash of clans has. Units can build on it and it's scrollable etc. I disagree with you when you say it's the only way. I have implemented a map scrolling system as well as pinch zooming. Maybe we aren't thinking of the same things because you are really knowledgable regarding unity and I see your posts on the forums all the time.

Comment: hi @savlon fair enough, the OP means like a "tiling system," sort of thing.  good point. i thought OP meant A SCROLLING MAP -- like you see on "maps.google.com" or any real estate site ... or indeed like you see on the linked example.  anyways thanks and cheers

Comment: @JoeBlow ahhh I see... I guess that's what happens when you use such as loose term as "map" lol... Everyone has a different thought when they hear it. All good mate, thanks for clarifying it.